# symfony/skeleton and symfony/website-skeleton

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

At https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html you are instructed to run:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project
```

whereas at http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html you are instructed to run:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton quick_tour
```

I have just done both. Using symfony/website-skeleton I got an error message in the browser: `No route found for "GET /"`

With symfony/skeleton I did get a `Welcome to Symfony 4.0.4` page.

What are the differences between the two and why would you use one rather than the other?

Comment: Same thing just happened to me yesterday, actually. I think their documentation needs an update.

Comment: Neither of them has a default GET / route defined.  If you look all the way down in the HTTPKernel class you will see that if the routing system itself is not initialized then a default welcome page is generated.  Hence a clean skeleton install gives you a default page.  But as soon as you install pretty much any other bundle then the route not found error will occur.  Just one of those annoying quirks.

Comment: Strictly speaking the welcome message is generated in the http-kernel RouterListener when matchRequest throws a NoConfiguration exception.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The new symfony edition (Symfony 4) is "**bundle less**".
Symfony core team decided to not provide the Symfony Standard Edition for Symfony 4.0 that means when you run `composer create-project symfony/skeleton` you download the minimum package to start an application and you have to download the over packages needed and you need to explicitly add all the dependencies you want to depend on (twig, routing...) [look here for other package](https://symfony.sh/) .
But it could be difficult for new comers and the Symfony core team dediced to provide an edition with the minimum common Symfony features.
You get it with `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton`.
You have more explanation [here](https://symfony.com/blog/the-end-of-the-symfony-standard-edition)

Answer (score 9):

Came here as a result of a similar search, but was more interested in what's under the hood.

Not to take away from the accepted answer, but for those who, like me, were after something more detailed, you can look at the package details in packagist and reviewing the dependencies noted in the requires and requires dev sub-sections:

https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/website-skeleton

**Includes**: framework, framework extra, console, asset, security, validator twig, doctrine, http client, serialiser, yaml, dotenv, flex, form and validator packages among others.

https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/skeleton

**Includes**: console, dotenv, flex, platform and yaml only.

Seems like a no brainer, but if you came here looking for it, it's there.